# Parsing datepicker values to perform a query to a mysql in Flask

Tags: python, flask, python-datetime, jquerydatetimepicker

I working with a dashboard project, it has a dashboard and it does build a query based on the days selected from the day picker, currently I was able to implement the date picker with Flask DateField form and it does work as expected.

```
class ExampleForm(Form):
    dt = DateField('DatePicker', format='%Y-%m-%d')
    dt2 = DateField('DatePicker', format='%Y-%m-%d')


<form action="" method="POST">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
   <a> Start Date {{ form.dt(class_='datepicker') }}</a>
   <a> End Date {{ form.dt2(class_='datepicker') }}</a>
<button class="w3-button w3-round-xlarge w3-teal w3-small w3-border " type="submit" value="submit"><b>Submit</b></button>
</form>
```

I would like to implement a more friendly solution like this one, https://www.daterangepicker.com/#example4 , where I can select multiple options or a date range.

Can this be achieved thru flask_wtf ?

I was looking for an answer in other questions but no success yet

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<form method="GET">
        <input type="hidden" id="start" name="startDate">
        <input type="hidden" id="end" name="endDate">
<div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>
<input type="submit">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
        var end = moment();

        function cb(start, end) {
            $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        }

        $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
            startDate: start,
            endDate: end,
            ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            }
        }, cb);

        cb(start, end);

    });
</script>
</form>
```

I cant return the selected values to my flask function.

any guide or help will be much appreciated